# Android java utf-8 encoded strings

Tags: java, android, character-encoding, zbar-sdk, zbar

I'm trying to build an Android application using the [zbar](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/) library to scan codes. I generated QRcodes with UTF-8 encoding and am using this Android app to scan them. The text I'm encoding is "L'étoile". I tried the default zbar test program and noticed that it doesn't display accented characters correctly. So I slightly modified its code below in order to debug it and understand why it's failing to display characters correctly.

```
byte[] bytes = sym.getDataBytes();
String latin1Result = new String(bytes, "ISO8859-1");
String utf8Result = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
Log.d("CUSTOM_DEBUG_TAG", "result " + sym.getData() + ", string " + sym.getData().toString() + ". latin1 result " + latin1Result + ". utf8 result " + utf8Result);
```

From the log I get:

```
CUSTOM_DEBUG_TAG(11987): result L'ﾃｩtoile, string L'ﾃｩtoile. latin1 result L'ï¾ï½©toile. utf8 result L'ﾃｩtoile
```

I'm a bit lost when it comes to character sets and encodings so please bear with me.
From the log above, can I affirm that the zbar library is actually returning a UTF-8 encoded string "L'étoile"? If so, shouldn't it display correctly in the log?

I believe zbar uses iconv and defaults to ISO-8859-1. So I also tried to generate a QRcode with iso-8859-1 encoded text. I then tried to read the QRcode with the Android application and the log showed this:

```
CUSTOM_DEBUG_TAG(11987): result L'騁oile, string L'騁oile. latin1 result L'é¨oile. utf8 result L'騁oile
```

So as you can see I'm unable to retrieve the accented string "L'étoile".
Obviously, there are concepts I'm unable to grasp and am hoping for some help.

By the way, if I scan the same QRcode with applications such as QR Droid or Zxing, I get the string correctly displayed as "L'étoile" (thus I'm discarding the fact that there could be problems with the QRcode itself).

Thanks

Comment: what do you get when you create new String from the bytes without using an encoding ?

Comment: The code would be `byte[] bytes = sym.getDataBytes();
String Result = new String(bytes);
Log.d("CUSTOM_DEBUG_TAG", "Result " + Result);
` and if I use a utf-8 encoded QRcode I get: `Result L'ﾃｩtoile`

Comment: try not to use any encoding like String data = new String(bytes); what that gives you ?

Comment: and if I scan an ISO-8859-1 encoded QRcode then the result is `Result L'騁oile`

Answer (score 5):

After some trial and error, it seems that zbar don't use the ISO-8859-1 encoding but the Shift_JIS when special characters are found. Here what works for me:

```
byte[] b = sym.getData().getBytes("Shift_JIS");
String value = new String(b, "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a missing dash (-).

```
String latin1Result = new String(bytes, "ISO-8859-1");
```

Simply using new String(bytes) will use the default platform encoding, which creates a not very portable application.

If that does not help, try string literals to see whether the problem lies with the outputting.

```
String result = "\u00e9toile";
```

Comment: if my code is: `byte[] bytes = sym.getDataBytes(); String Result = new String(bytes); String latin1Result = new String(bytes, "ISO-8859-1"); String utf8Result = new String(bytes, "UTF-8"); String literalResult = "\u00e9toile"; Log.d("CUSTOM_DEBUG_TAG", "result " + sym.getData() + ", string " + sym.getData().toString() + ". latin1 result " + latin1Result + ". utf8 result " + utf8Result + ". Result " + Result + ". literalResult " + literalResult);`

Comment: then the log output is: `CUSTOM_DEBUG_TAG(13422): result L'ﾃｩtoile, string L'ﾃｩtoile. latin1 result L'ï¾ï½©toile. utf8 result L'ﾃｩtoile. Result L'ﾃｩtoile. literalResult étoile`.  So what does this suggest? That the zbar library is giving me a corrupt array?

Comment: Yes, give the zbar forums/FAQ/HowTos a try. I found the [same problem](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zbar/forums/forum/1072195/topic/5068736). Sorry I could not help.

Comment: The zbar forum post you refer to actually hints that an iOS user has successfully displayed the string via encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding. However, it doesn't seem to be the case here. Anyway, I think zbar is the culprit because the same encoding issues were found with zbar command-line tools. So thanks anyway, even though my problem is unsolved. At least I know now that it seems to be an issue with the external library.

Comment: Success with your further search.